# Thymeleaf not loading template

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I am using Spring and Thymeleaf. Thanks to xerx593, I was able to get it working so I updated this question to show the working code.

Here is my application class

```
package com.propfinancing.www;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.layoutdialect.LayoutDialect;

@Controller
@SpringBootApplication
public class PfWebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(PfWebApplication.class, args);
  }
  
  @Bean
  public LayoutDialect layoutDialect() {
    return new LayoutDialect();
  }

  @GetMapping("/page1.html")
  public String page1() {
    return "page1";
  }
}
```

Next, I create a layout.html file in src/main/resources/templates/layout.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">

<body>
    This is the layout template
    <div layout:fragment="content">
        <p>This is were the content will go</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And fin
ally, I created /ser/main/resources/templates/page1.html to use the template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" 
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      layout:decorate="~{layout}">
      
<body>      
  <div layout:fragment="content">
    This is the content of page 1.
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

When I go to http://dev.propfinancing.com/www/page1.html, it gives me the template driven output I was expecting.

Thanks!
Neil

Comment: I added this to my templateEngine() method:
`LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass()).error("In templateEngine()");`
and I see the output in the log so I know the method is getting called.

Comment: I also added `logging.level.root=TRACE` to my application.properties file.  I get a lot of output, but not sure what to look for.

Comment: `logging.level.web=debug` should be enough & more readable.

Comment: Good suggestion!

Comment: Welcome! :-) Please also consider to accept/vote answer, if/when it helped;)

Comment: I can't vote for the answer, apparently I don't have enough reputation yet :(

Comment: That will be fine! ;) ...with time. But *you can accept* (also own answers;)!

Comment: Also (tip for newcomer): Don't edit your question with the working solution, but better: provide a new/edit my(with more rep.!?) answer! ;)

Comment: Thanks for the tips!  I will keep them in mind for the future!

Comment: Thank You for question & rep! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious mistake:

1. > I created a simple html page called `page1.html` in my `src/main/resources/static` directory

   (This is super for (spring-web) static content, but...)
2. > And finally, I **updated** my `page1.html` to use the template...

*Updating* is not enough, you have to also **move** it to a configured template location! So moving the file to **`src/main/resources/templates/`** (default location, <s>issuing *same* browser request,</s>) will hopefully/probably produce the desired result(, **or at least throw an exception**).

---

In short: `src/main/resources/static` directory is not intended for templates! (It can still be configured, but this would be very strange/hacky/bunch full of "side effects"!?).

---

Ok, the 404, can be fixed (simply) with:

```java
@Controller // !
@SpringBootApplication
public class ThymeleafTestApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ThymeleafTestApplication.class, args);
  }

  @GetMapping("/page1.html") // !!
  public String page1() {
    return "page1"; // returning the view name
  }
// ...
}
```

i.e. by providing a "controller" for this "view".

Or  by configuring:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class PfWebApplication // extends ... 
   implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void addViewControllers (ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
      ViewControllerRegistration r = registry.addViewController("/page1.html");
      r.setViewName("page1");
      // r.set...
  }
...
```

---

One important thing is, that:

```java
  @Bean
  public LayoutDialect layoutDialect() { 
    return new LayoutDialect();
  }
```

is the "auto-configuration" approach, which equips us with "all the spring (boot) magic".

Whereas:

```java
  @Bean
  public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.addDialect(new LayoutDialect());
    return templateEngine;
  }
```

..is the "DIY" approach, and we'd have to tune (like e.g. [spring-boot does](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/4256344c80a2dcb7de93383f47d08aca0522ab28/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.java#L137)).

Links:

- https://ultraq.github.io/thymeleaf-layout-dialect/
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#web
- https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html

Comment: When I moved page1.html to the templates directory, I get a 404 error when I go to `http://dev.propfinancing.com/www/page1.html` What do I need to do to load it now?

Comment: I am trying myself (jar, embedded), please meanwhile inspect the stacktraces (sorry, i also produced 2-3 on `/www/templates/page1.html`, without `/templates/`, `.html` (brute force) ;) ..its also much in the "environment" and "other libs&config" details.

Comment: see update, bro

Comment: I tried to follow your first example of using @Controller (See my updated code above).  When I go to `http://dev.propfinancing.com/www/page1.html`, I just get "page1", I don't get any of the templates.

Comment: also my bad: please replace the `SpringTemplateEngine` bean with `LayoutDialect` ([ref](https://ultraq.github.io/thymeleaf-layout-dialect/getting-started/)), because the latter uses (spring boot) auto configuration, whereas the first is the "DIY" approach (then we'd have to do the analogous to [src-link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/4256344c80a2dcb7de93383f47d08aca0522ab28/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.java#L137)

Comment: That worked!  I knew it had to be some simple things, but the resources I found on the web were not complete.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was in the use of `decorator` I solved this issue by simply changing `decorator` to `decorate`

Here I had the error when I used decorator to configure the created template using `Thymeleaf`

```html
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
    layout:decorator="template1">
```

Then I changed the decorator keyword to decorate and it just worked fine :

```html
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
    layout:decorate="template1">
```

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer, @Alix.